# jenkins can't see anaconda python

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, anaconda

Trying to get jenkins to work with anaconda python. I'm using the shiningpanda plugin and python plugin.

Whenever I try to set the python installation to point to my python 2.7 executable, `/home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python2.7`, I get the message that it is neither a directory nor an executable. Is there some 2.7 compatibility problem?

Edit:
Here's my python info

```
# which python
/home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python2
# ls -l /home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     7 Oct  9 17:02 /home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Oct  9 17:02 /home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10038 Oct  9 17:02 /home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1600 Oct  9 17:02 /home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1678 Oct  9 17:02 /home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python-config
```

Not sure how to give evidence on the error. I go to `Jenkins > configuration > Python > Python Installations`. Under `Home or executable` I put `/home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python2.7`, `/home/lminer/anaconda/bin/python`, `/home/lminer/anaconda/bin/`. And each time a message in red below the box reads: `Neither a directory nor an executable`

I don't get this issue if I instead point to `/usr/bin/python2.6`

Comment: Can you post an example of you getting this error, as well as an example verifying that you do actually have a python2.7 executable or symlink at that path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't set permissions correctly. The directory is recognized once I let everyone execute from it. If there's a better way to do this, perhaps by moving python to a different location, let me know.